# Nav Bar and Header Combined

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to find out a way to make my nav bar and header title a part of each other. In other words, I'd like the text for my header to be on top of my nav bar or a part of it, as well as both the nav and the header text to be fixed to the top of the page for scrolling. I've been playing around and have gotten no where. I'm not really sure how to control the css and html for it.

```css
header {
  /*insert something here?*/
}

nav {
  background-image: url("header.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  padding: 1%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: orange;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size 17px;
  font-family: helvetica;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

nav li,
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

nav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

nav .material-icons {
  display: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: blue;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  nav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  nav .material-icons {
    float: left;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  Knox Enterprises Inc.
  <nav>
    <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="About.html">About</a>
    <a href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make `header` `display: flex` and use `justify-content: space-between` to separate them - or you can remove that for the text and nav to be side-by-side on the left, or `justify-content: center` to put them in the center or `justify-content: flex-end` to put them on the right. Put the text in an `h1` or some other element if it's more appropriate, then add `position: fixed; width: 100%` to keep it pinned to the top of the page.

```css
body {
  min-height: 500vh;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  align-items: center;
}

nav {
  background-image: url("header.jpg");
background-position: center;
        padding: 1%;
        overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%; 
  transform: translateY(-50%);
    }

 @media (max-width: 900px) {
   nav { position: static; transform: translateY(0); }
   header { justify-content: space-between; }
 }

    nav a {
        float: left;
        display: block;
        color: orange;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size 17px;
        font-family: helvetica;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
    }

    nav li, nav ul{
        list-style: none;
    }

    nav a:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
        color: black;
    }

    nav .material-icons {
        display: none;
        font-size: 36px;
        color: blue;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      nav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
      nav .material-icons {
        float: left;
        display: block;
      }
    }
htmlcss
```

```html
<header>

        <nav>
            <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="About.html">About</a>
            <a href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
        </nav>
        
        <h1>Knox Enterprises Inc.</h1>

    </header>
```

Comment: quick question, as you can see, this pushed my nav menu to the right. How would i make the nav menu back on the left how it was originally and the Title/logo centered?

Comment: @A.Student sorry, I didn't realize I posted the CSS twice in the answer! I thought I reviewed it but obviously didn't :) Just updated - how's that?

Comment: that worked, except on mine the title is before the nav for some reason. not sure why :)

Comment: one last question. I see that this center aligns both the nav and the header. Is there a way to just center the Name, Knox Enterprises in the <h1> and have the nav left aligned?

Comment: @A.Student widen the window and make the window wider/smaller - the nav is on the left and the text is centered. I center align the two at the point that they're about to overlap using the `@media (max-width: 900px)` media query. You can remove that if you want, or adjust the width in the media query.

Answer (score 1):

You right placed in the `header` text and navigation, however, in order to easily manipulate the position of the text using `css` it should be placed inside a `div`, `p` or `span`.

In order for your title stick in scroll to the top of the page there is `position: fixed`. When using it, don't forget to give the parent of the header (ex. `body`) `position: relative`.

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #bbc;
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 16px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  padding: 16px;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

p {
  text-indent: 2em;
```

```html
<header>
  <span>Knox Enterprises Inc.</span>
  <nav>
    <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="About.html">About</a>
    <a href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
  </nav>
</header>
<main>
  <h1>I'm trying to find out a way</h1>
  <p>I'm trying to find out a way to make my nav bar and header title a part of each other. In other words, I'd like the text for my header to be on top of my nav bar or a part of it, as well as both the nav and the header text to be fixed to the top of
    the page for scrolling. I've been playing around and have gotten no where. I'm not really sure how to control the css and html for it.
  </p>
  <p>I'm trying to find out a way to make my nav bar and header title a part of each other. In other words, I'd like the text for my header to be on top of my nav bar or a part of it, as well as both the nav and the header text to be fixed to the top of
    the page for scrolling. I've been playing around and have gotten no where. I'm not really sure how to control the css and html for it.
  </p>
  <p>I'm trying to find out a way to make my nav bar and header title a part of each other. In other words, I'd like the text for my header to be on top of my nav bar or a part of it, as well as both the nav and the header text to be fixed to the top of
    the page for scrolling. I've been playing around and have gotten no where. I'm not really sure how to control the css and html for it.
  </p>
</main>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: this worked, just have to play around and edit it now. thanks.

Comment: quick question, as you can see, this pushed my nav menu to the right. How would i make the nav menu back on the left how it was originally and the Title/logo centered?

Comment: @A.Student easy change my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```css
header>div {
  display:inline;
  float:left
        /*insert something here?*/
    }

    nav {
 display:inline;
 width:auto;
        background-image: url("header.jpg");
        background-position: center;
        padding: 1%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    nav a {
        float: left;
        display: block;
        color: orange;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size 17px;
        font-family: helvetica;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
    }

    nav li, nav ul{
        list-style: none;
    }

    nav a:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
        color: black;
    }

    nav .material-icons {
        display: none;
        font-size: 36px;
        color: blue;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      nav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
      nav .material-icons {
        float: left;
        display: block;
      }
    }
```

```html
<header>
        <div>Knox Enterprises Inc.</div>
  
        <nav>
            <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="About.html">About</a>
            <a href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
        </nav>
  
    </header>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Thanks for that, I understand your point, but I think there are things that explain themselves and I think this is one case of that, the code is simple enough to explain. On the other hand, I am not very good with English and I am afraid to write wrong